# Unable to get all Video files from storage Android

Tags: java, android, mediastore

Am using following method to get video files from storage. it retrieves only directories files but not read files inside sub-directory files.

**Example:-** i can read file from `WhatsApp Video` but in the same folder there is a sub folder name `sent` i can't read the files inside.

any help, how can i read all folder and sub-folder

```
public class GetVideos {

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
    public void getAllVideosData(Context context, ArrayList<VideoViewInfo> AllVideosData) {

        String[] projection = new String[] {
                MediaStore.Video.Media._ID,
                MediaStore.Video.Media.TITLE,
                MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.DATA,
                MediaStore.Video.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME,
                MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_TAKEN,
                MediaStore.Video.Media.DURATION,
                MediaStore.Video.Media.RESOLUTION,
                MediaStore.Video.Media.SIZE
    };

        Uri Video = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        String orderBy = MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_TAKEN;

        @SuppressLint("Recycle")
        Cursor cur = context.getContentResolver().query(Video, projection,null,null,orderBy );
        assert cur != null;
        Log.i("ListingVideo"," query count=" + cur.getCount());

        if (cur.moveToNext()) {
            String id;
            String title;
            String filePath;
            String bucketName;
            String date;
            String duration;
            String resolution;
            String size;

            int tempId = cur.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.Media._ID);
            int titleTemp = cur.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.Media.TITLE);
            int filePathTemp = cur.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA);
            int bucketTemp = cur.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME);
            int dateTemp = cur.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_TAKEN);
            int durationTemp = cur.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.Media.DURATION);
            int resolutionTemp = cur.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.Media.RESOLUTION);
            int sizeTemp = cur.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.Media.SIZE);
            do {
                id = cur.getString(tempId);
                title = cur.getString(titleTemp);
                filePath = cur.getString(filePathTemp);
                bucketName = cur.getString(bucketTemp);
                date = cur.getString(dateTemp);
                duration = cur.getString(durationTemp);
                resolution = cur.getString(resolutionTemp);
                size = cur.getString(sizeTemp);
                Log.d(TAG, "getAllVideosData: "+bucketName);
                VideoViewInfo vvi = new VideoViewInfo(id, title, filePath, bucketName, date, duration, resolution, size);
                AllVideosData.add(vvi);

            } while (cur.moveToNext());
        }
    }
}
```

What should i do to get all video file in my storage ?

> Bountry reward
> i want to read every video file from storage
> with above code i can only read files limited location as per `MediaStore.Video`

Comment: Define "some file" and " i can't read" ... There is main problem with this code(as it was stated in multiple answer to similar questions) ... **You should not try to read video as file ... obviously some content providers doesn't return file path (as such may basically doesn't  not exist or it's private)**

Comment: @Selvin as i metioned i was able to read file from  `WhatsApp Video` folder but in the same folder there is a sub folder name `sent` i can't read files in the `sent` folfer

Comment: Duplicate of [Android - Get filename and path of URI from mediastore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52792939/android-get-filename-and-path-of-uri-from-mediastore) <= yes, there is more poular one but this one has a real  answer ...

Comment: @Selvin first and only problem is i was not able to read the video file inside `sent` 
 directory child of `WhatsApp Video` but i can read files inside  `WhatsApp Video`. So how do i read `sent` directory files.

Comment: your first and only problem is that your whole code is wrong  ... from the answer ***There is no requirement for a Uri to refer to a file on the filesystem that you can access, and there is no requirement that your query() supports a DATA column.***

Comment: @Selvin So what should i do ?.

Comment: You should use method from ContentResolver mentioned in the answer

Comment: @Selvin where should i use `ContentResolver` ?. can you show a small example ?

Comment: @Selvin `Cursor cur = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(Video).query(Video, projection,null,null,orderBy );` here is what i tried after adding `throws FileNotFoundException` i get error saying `cannot resolve method query in input stream`.

Comment: "it retrieves only directories files but not read files inside sub-directory files" -- no, it retrieves whatever has been indexed by `MediaStore`. The decision of what gets indexed is made jointly by the developers of `MediaStore` and by the publisher of the content (in this case, Facebook, apparently). If Facebook does not want those particular videos indexed in `MediaStore`, that is Facebook's decision. "What should i do to get all video file in my storage ?" -- in general, you don't. You are welcome to try using filesystem APIs, but that may not be an option for you starting next year.

Comment: @CommonsWare so how can i read all video and index them ?,

Comment: In general, you don't. You are welcome to try using filesystem APIs, but that may not be an option for you starting next year.

Comment: @CommonsWare so what is the solution?. Any alternate method?

Comment: what's up sent file is private do you try to read from sub folder in anthor folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run a recursive function to list all video files like

```java
void findVideos(File dir, ArrayList<String> list){
    for (File file : dir.listFiles()) {
        if (file.isDirectory()) findVideos(file, list);
        else if(file.getAbsolutePath().contains(".mp4")) list.add(file.getAbsolutePath());
    }
}
```

Or you can query the mediastore like done in this repository [here](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/blob/v7.6/DragDrop/Action/app/src/main/java/com/commonsware/android/dragdrop/MainActivity.java#L123-L139)

Comment: If I use this, how do I get video file duration and size?

Answer (score 0):

**`It's really hard and full of a mess when doing file handling`**
because you only access the files but what about the subdirectories in it? well in the case of

@Kursh's answer **recursion will not help either**

because it will just go deep into the sub directories never to come back I had developed the algorithm but it was not really inefficient, but you can use [this](https://github.com/jiajunhui/MediaLoader) library and remember to use it in an **ASYNC TAK** or **Coroutine**